# Prove that there is at most one function that verifies

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

let $f$ be a function defined on $\mathbb R$ of class $C^2$ and $g$ is a function of class $C^2$

Prove that there is at most one function that verifies $$g(x)=f(x)+\int_{0}^{x} (x-t)g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$$

I tried everything I knew, I got to the following equation: Let $s =  \int_{0}^{x} G(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$ ($G'=g$ and $g(0)=0$) then it verifies $s^{\prime\prime} - s = f^{\prime\prime}(x)$, but by doing this I  can't prove that the function is unique.

Comment: Which function do we need to prove this for? $g$ or $f$?

Comment: Should the integral be $\int_0^x (x-t) g(t) dt?$

Comment: If your given equation prevails then you get a direct solution for $g$ as $g(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{1-x^2/2}$, but I do not think that is your question.

Comment: What do you mean by ' verifies ' ?

Answer (score 0):

This answer assume that $f$ is given and you want to prove uniqueness for $g$.

Assume that you have two functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ that satisfies your equation. Let $h=g_1-g_2$. Then (check this yourself) $h$ satisfies $h(0)=0$, $h'(0)=0$ and $h''(x)=h(x)$. Conclude that $h=0$, so $g_1=g_2$.

I could give more details if necessary, but I prefer you to fill them in.